# Can't force a Form Submit button color change

Tags: forms, button, colors

I am trying to force a color change to the default button of a Form Submit.  I know having this style in-line isn't the best approach, but I am just doing it for testing purposes, once I have it working, I'll pull into my CSS.

Any suggestions on what I need to do differently to force the color to change?  Thanks in advance.

```
<style type="text/css">
.button
{
width:205px;
height: 25px;
color: #bda935;
line-height: 20px;
padding-bottom: 2px;
vertical-align: middle;
font-family: "Lucida Grande", Geneva, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 13px;
<!--font-weight: bold;-->
text-transform: none;
border:1px solid transparent;
}
.button:hover
{
    background-image:url('tiny_.gif');
}
</style>
<form action = "Contact Us.cshtml">
      <input type="submit" class="button" value="Request More Information">
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I found worked.

I needed to add !important after my background-color: #bda935 in my CSS.  So, it now looks like this:

```
.button
{
width:205px;
height: 25px;
background-color: #bda935 !important;
color: #bda935;
line-height: 20px;
padding-bottom: 2px;
vertical-align: middle;
font  : 10pt 'Century Gothic';
color : #000000;
font-size: 13px;
<!--font-weight: bold;-->
text-transform: none;
border:1px solid transparent;
}
```